Nuxt app styling becomes wrong after page reload
I built an app, deployed it to server.
Initially after visiting the page styling was correct but after reloading the page it gets messed up. I'm not sure why it's happening like this. Is there someone who would know what could be possible cause?
I added this part to nuxt config file, but it did not solve the issue.
  features: {
    inlineStyles: false,  
  },

I'm using vuesax. And I wrote css to overwrite some of components stylings.
It's like when page is reloaded it reverts all of overwritten css
EDIT
When I inspect element which has modified style I see the file where css is written - _nuxt/index.UXqOsbsu.css
but after page reload I see the file is not displayed there and thus style gets messed up

Hard to help without a [repro] or more details.

I mean what other details I can provide? It's there all that is, I have declared all css in index.vue without scope. In dev mode when I reload the page it stlll working fine but when app is built and deployed on server, when visiting on first try it works but when reloaded it becomes wrong (styling)

Do you still have the issue if you build and run locally? Also, where are you hosting it? Do you have any errors in your console? _nuxt/index.UXqOsbsu.css will not help because it is a random number anyway. What kind of CSS are you using there? This is important and trying to have something not working as minimal as possible is important.

I just solved the issue, instead of declaring stylings in each page/component I created assets folder and in assets created another folder named css and in there created main.css. Wrote all css in main.css

Not really a solution but at least, works as a workaround. :3

Isn't it the best practise to do what I did?

by the way, _nuxt/index.UXqOsbsu.css was not random number, it's all of custom css stylings bundled together (from each page/component), I just declared main.css in certain directory and linked it to nuxt config. Now it works fine.

I mean a main CSS file is not really the same thing. You can still do CSS in it of course but it does not solve the issue per se. Yeah it is the given file but with a random hash for cache purposes.
